# Persist cookies data in webview in electron js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webview, electron, electron-builder

I am currently developing an Electron app that involves multiple webviews, each hosting a distinct website requiring user login. However, I've encountered a persistent data loss issue: whenever I restart the app, all the previously logged-in sessions and data within the webviews seem to vanish. I have attempted to address this by saving and injecting cookies, but unfortunately, the problem persists.

Webview Component

```js
<webview
  disablewebsecurity
  nodeintegration
  style={{ width: '800px', height: '300px' }}
  id="view2"
  partition="1"
  src="https://onlyfans.com/"
  ref={webview1}
/>
```

IPC Channels

```js
ipcMain.on('webview-loaded' as IPCChannels, async () => {
  const cookies = await session.fromPartition('1').cookies.get({});
  settings.setSync({ webview: JSON.stringify(cookies) });
  mainWindow.webContents.send('webview-cookies-extracted' as IPCChannels, cookies);
});

ipcMain.on('initializing-webview' as IPCChannels, async () => {
  try {
    const settingsDefault = (await settings.get('webview')) as string;
    const syncedCookies = JSON.parse(settingsDefault) as Cookie[];

    syncedCookies.forEach(async (cookie) => {
      const {
        domain,
        expirationDate,
        httpOnly,
        name,
        path,
        sameSite,
        secure,
        value,
      } = cookie;

      const cookieDetails = {
        url: `https://${domain}`,
        name,
        value,
        domain,
        path,
        secure,
        httpOnly,
        expirationDate,
        session: cookie.session,
        sameSite,
      };

      mainWindow.webContents.send(
        'persisted-cookies-extracted' as IPCChannels,
        cookieDetails
      );
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

ipcMain.on('inject-cookies' as IPCChannels, (a, cookie: any) => {
  console.log(cookie);
  console.log(session.fromPartition('1').isPersistent());
  session.fromPartition('1').cookies.set(cookie);
});
```